# How to find a partial numeric value in column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame created with Pandas. It has 3 columns. One of them has the date in the format %Y%m%d%H. I need to find the rows that match a date with the format %Y%m%d.

I tried

```
df.loc[df["MESS_DATUM"] == 20170807]
```

which doesn't work. Only when I do

```
df.loc[df["MESS_DATUM"] == 2017080723]
```

it works for that single line. But I need the other lines containing the date only (without the hour). I know there is something like `.str.cotains("")`. Is there something similar for numeric values or a way to use wildcards in the lines above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can "integer divide" `MESS_DATUM` column by `100`:

```
df.loc[df["MESS_DATUM"]//100 == 20170807]
```

Demo:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   MESS_DATUM
0  2017080719
1  2017080720
2  2017080721
3  2017080722
4  2017080723

In [30]: df.dtypes
Out[30]:
MESS_DATUM    int64
dtype: object

In [31]: df["MESS_DATUM"]//100
Out[31]:
0    20170807
1    20170807
2    20170807
3    20170807
4    20170807
Name: MESS_DATUM, dtype: int64
```

---

But I would consider converting it to `datetime` dtype:

```
df["MESS_DATUM"] = pd.to_datetime(df["MESS_DATUM"].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H')
```

If `df["MESS_DATUM"]` is of `float` dtype, then we can use the following trick:

```
In [41]: pd.to_datetime(df["MESS_DATUM"].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0], 
                        format='%Y%m%d%H')
Out[41]:
0   2017-08-07 19:00:00
1   2017-08-07 20:00:00
2   2017-08-07 21:00:00
3   2017-08-07 22:00:00
4   2017-08-07 23:00:00
Name: MESS_DATUM, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: The first command works perfectly fine. Can you explain what it does? As I need to change to a date format anyway I tested the second approach as well. But I am running into a `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0`. Not sure whats causing it. i guess the Type fo the df or the column?

Comment: @BallerNacken, i've added a small demo... What is the dtype of `MESS_DATUM` - i guess it's float? Do you want to preserve an `hour` part when converting `df["MESS_DATUM"]` to datetime dtype?

Comment: Yes `MESS_DATUM` is float. And yeah I need to preserve the hour.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks!